# What's happens to Mundy's arm?

Tags: cloverfield, the-cloverfield-paradox

Is there any explanation for what happens to Mundy's arm in *The Cloverfield Paradox*?

First off, what is supposed to be happening with the bulkhead? A hole opens and moves around... why? Nothing else is doing this and nothing like this occurs again.

After being cut off, his arm starts moving on its own. Is it an alien? Possessed?

And how does his arm know something that none of the characters could? Is it also omnipresent?

Is there *any* in-universe explanation for any of this?

Comment: Saw the film last night.  They gave no explanation for it, nor for the magnetic anomaly which eventually kills him.  My guess is they had an explanation, but it got left on the cutting room floor.

Comment: I believe it is implied that the Shepherd caused a bunch of dimensional anomalies (wibbly wobbly, if you will).

Comment: I think the arm is still attached interdimensionally (is that even a word?) to the other Mundy in universe B, but only the arm is present in universe A. It would explain the knowledge it has and the fact that it doesn't bleed.

Comment: The arm is the REAL paradox.

Answer (score 3):

I think the arm is still attached interdimensionally (is that even a word?) to the other Mundy in universe B, but only the arm is present in universe A. It would explain the knowledge it has about a certain item and the fact that it doesn't bleed even though it should be.

I suspect there is another arm in universe B that belongs to Mundy from universe A holding up the middle finger.

As for the bulkhead event, probably a moving gateway between both universes that got created and eventually ends up closing and separating Mundy from his arm.

Comment: But if it belongs to B-Mundy, why didn't it die with him when the B-Cloverfield Station crashed?

Comment: Because timelines aren't synchronized.

Comment: I have to say I really like this answer. Yet we still have serious problems...  Assuming this arm is connected to B-Murdy, how did it know where to "crawl"? How would B-Mundy know A-Mundy was unaware of this apparently vital information and thus write it? How would he even know the arm was there, unless A-Mundy's arm appeared somewhere and did something THEY didn't know. I don't know about you, but if I lost my arm and then another appeared and just sat there I'd assume it was mine. It all seems sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if they didn't have the knowledge of the gyroscope and stay stuck for enough time to be too late to save the world, then Mundy's arm is found in the ship giving the middle finger for anyone, futures Mundy would easily realize that is arms travel through time and not between universes. See, it's the reaction of past was being done in his present time, now aware that maybe his arm is in the past, he uses his remaining time to give all the essential data he gathered since he has no time to save himself. Change the past by sending info cross time would save everyone, so he desperately crawled until being found where he could give the message to save the two universes in the past, since he got stuck looking for the gyroscope for so much time, this was the only info about his time he could provide.

About the wall that for me is simple at least when two beings inhabit the same universe, the universe fix itself by killing both sometimes, so... as I saw many deaths were caused by a chain of events that for me means the universe fixing itself, the only excuse for me is Volkov (in my theory) he shares the body of the B universe into one luring him to attack the saboteur of his reality thinking was the same due to brain merge, as I saw everything on the ship was teleported into him, the worms, the gyroscope, and tragically parts of him of B universe, since he look's like to be talking to someone, I think it's his consciousness of B universe aware of a traitor, but confuse enough to not being aware of his own death. If got any question please say I will try check the post after some time. I think was not clear so I will put in a few words, resume about Mundy was (A past universe) and (B future universe) arms, and not dimensional.

Comment: Your  "theory" could use some serious formatting, it's almost entirely one long sentence that rambles on aimlessly, I'm sure this answer would be better if it had some better formatting to make your point more clear. You've also failed to give any explanation for what happened with Mundy's arm.

Comment: his arms travel time, not dimension travel, but time, the severed arm was from a future Mundy. who didn't find where the gyroscope was and fail to travel back to his dimension. Because the more time they stay in another dimension, they start to dying from random things (like the dimension was killing them), if they fail to find the gyroscope fast they would be doomed, mundy's arm was middle fingering the future lost crew that find the gyroscope too late, the mundy from future easy realize that was his first reaction after lost his arm, and saw this as a chance to send a message to past.

Comment: about the formatting, i agreed. too many things to say, not enough words.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the paradox. Mundy sees the arm and does the same thing, warning the crew from another dimension causing a domino effect through the multiverse.

Comment: Why do you think this is the case? It seems fairly speculative?

Comment: indeed in the film we got no clue about this but i guess its fit in the premise about infinit universes, because its a very important information why not try to do the same and save some peoples?

Comment: like a buttlerfly effect lol